# I need to add onClickListener to a bunch of ImageButtons

Tags: android, button, onclick, listener, imagebutton

I have created a bunch of `ImageButtons` programmatically while in a for loop. They have worked fine as the data displayed in a `HorizontalScrollView`. Now I need each one to go dim or bright when clicked. First click will setAlpha(45); second click will setAlpha(255);.

I don't think I fully understand how the Views and `onClickListener` works yet. It seems the `onClick` function examples I find take a View. How would that function know which button is clicked? Perhaps there is an easier way to do what I want?

Here are the `ImageButtons`.

```
TableRow tr0 = new TableRow(this);
tr0.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

for(int but=0; but<ClueList.size(); but++){
   ImageButton clueBut = new ImageButton(this);
      clueBut.setBackgroundResource(0);
      clueBut.setImageBitmap(ClueList.get(but).btmp);
      //clueBut.setOnClickListener(this);

      tr0.addView(clueBut);
}
```

Is there something I need to do to make the buttons identifiable? And how would that pass in through into the onClick function to be used?

-: Added Information :-
I am starting to wonder if the problem isn't with the buttons, but with the way I built the screen. More information added.

The Game activity is the main game, which uses the PuzzleView for the upper part of the screen holding the game grid. The lower part is where the ImageButtons are and I built them in place in the Game class.

```
public class Game extends Activity{
   //various variables and stuff

   private PuzzleView puzzleView;    // The PuzzleView is from another .java file
                                     // public class PuzzleView extends View

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      LinearLayout mainPanel = new LinearLayout(this);
      mainPanel.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICLE);

      puzzleView = new PuzzleView(this);
      mainPanel.addView(puzzleView);

      HorizontalScrollView bottom = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
      mainPanel.addView(bottom);

      TableLayout clues = new TableLayout(this);
      bottom.addView(clues);

      TableRow tr0 = new TableRow(this);
      for(int but=0; but<ClueList.size(); but++){
        ImageButton clueBut = new ImageButton(this);
        clueBut.setImageBitmap(ClueList.get(but).btmp);

        tr0.addView(clueBut);
       }
```

When I try to add the ClickListener(this) I get errors about `this` not being able to be a `Game`. I have similar problems in the `onClick(View v)` function referencing the `View`. Are these problems because I am building the buttons in the Game Activity instead of a View class?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set up an `OnClickListener` and implement the `onClick(View v)` callback, it's the Dalvik VM the one that will call that method each time the View is clicked, and it will pass the View instance as a parameter. Thus, the code you write inside that method will be applied only to the View that received the click and not to any other View. Add something like this to your loop:

```
clueBut.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick (View v) {
    if (v.getAlpha() == 1f)
      v.setAlpha(0.2f);
    else
      v.setAlpha(1f);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have added more info above. These suggestions look similar to what I have found online, but I get errors relating to using `View` in the `onClick` or using `this` in `onClickListener`. Maybe I am building the screen wrong?

Comment: Your Activity is not implementing the OnClickListener interface, so you cannot use `clueBut.setOnClickListener(this);`. Either implement it (`public class Game extends Activity implements OnClickListener {`) or use the snippet I posted instead. If you get any error, please post it so I can understand what's your specific problem.

Comment: I have tried adding the `implements OnClickListener` to the Game class and I get the same error. `The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})` It seems the dialog pop-up I have when the game is done is interfering with what I am trying to do with these buttons. What would be the easiest way to fix this? I started trying to move the scrolling buttons into a different class, the way the PuzzleView is called in from another class, but it is having trouble getting to the Clues Linked List.

Comment: you need to implement View.OnClickListener instead. Just use the full name to differentiate from the other OnClickListener you imported: `public class Game extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {`

Comment: Either that, or use `clueBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Comment: I ended up resolving my issue by moving the finishing dialog into a separate java file similar to the way my keyboard pop-up was done from the example. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

In the onClick event:

```
public void onClick(View currentView) 
{
    Button currentButton = (Button)CurrentView;
    //Do whatever you need with that button here.
}
```

Comment: This seems simple, and looks similar to what I have found online. I think I may be building the screen wrong as the View currentView gives errors.

Answer (score 0):

To identify each view uniquely use the property

> View. setId(int)

In your case the code would look something like this

```
for(int but=0; but<ClueList.size(); but++){
   ImageButton clueBut = new ImageButton(this);
      clueBut.setBackgroundResource(0);
      clueBut.setImageBitmap(ClueList.get(but).btmp);
      clueBut.setId(but);
      //clueBut.setOnClickListener(this);

      tr0.addView(clueBut);
}
```

Inside the onclick listener match the id of the view using `findViewByID()`

Comment: I did try to add the setID(but) into the loop. I still got errors with the setOnClickListener(this). Perhaps there is something I am doing wrong relating to the Layout of the screen. I did add more info above.

Comment: Good point. It is there, I just missed putting it up here. After the for loop making the buttons, there is `clues.addView(tr0,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));` and then `setContentView(mainPanel);`

Comment: Sorry for asking much questions than resolving the doubt.But in the given code the TableLayout is added to HorizontalScrollView but the Table row is not been added to TableLayout. Is that the isseu?

Comment: Perhaps that is an issue. I have the `clues.addView(tr0,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));` line. Since I am new to Android, I thought that would be doing that. I was able to get a horizontal scrolling section with the image buttons. I actually have three rows of buttons, but cut some of that out to simplify things here. Do you think I am not adding the Table Row to the Table Layout properly?